# In javascript how do I access the wordpress page name?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am running wordpress with Kadence theme.

I would like to change the text according to which page it is.

I have written this snippet:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header-custom");
x[0].innerHTML = "New Text";
</script>
```

I would like to add a condition

eg  if (pagename == the-page-name)

What is the element to use to for the page name?

Thanks

Comment: `document.title` perhaps? It depends what you mean by "page name".

Comment: If you mean the WP post title, then you will have to get that value using PHP (as it's a server side value) and inject it in to the JS (which runs on the client side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the page title you get it like this:

```
const pageTitle = document.title;
```

And if you need the page name in the URL(e.g: `about` in `https://mywebsite.com/about`) you get it like this:

```
const url = window.location.href;
const wordAfterUrl = url.split('/').pop();
```

Sometimes, the title and the word after the domain name are the same.